# Calculate age ONLY if DOB is present

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a large file that I am working on and need to be able to calculate people DOB. I have attached a sample file here to get an idea.... but basically what I am looking to do is ONLY if data exists in the "DOB" column, for "Age" to be calculated.

DOB will be listed in every other column for up to 18 different people (so column A, C, E.....)  In columns B, D, F..... I am looking to have the age be calculated in years.

The catch is, there will NOT always be data for 18 people, so this is something that would only need to calculate IF data is present in the DOB column.

Ideally this would be a macro that I would run when I open the file so that all of the ages can update.

How do I even go about doing something like this?

I would expect output to just show age in years.... so if DOB was 01/01/2001 - age would show as 18

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn’t just use a formula?

Comment: I don't see the attached file you mentioned.

Comment: If you're trying to use VBA, it's always useful to post the code you tried, and describe the exact problem(s) you had with it.

Comment: VBA is probably overkill for this.  A simple formula would work, so if starting cell is A2 then `IF(OFFSET(A2,0,1) <> "",DAYS(TODAY(),OFFSET(A2,0,1)) / 365, "")`  could be improved too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption that VBA is overkill.  This worked for me ...

```
=IF(A1="","",ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(A1,NOW()),0))
```

[image]

If you were looking at a VBA solution, the above formula is translatable directly to VBA.  It's not complete in relation to your context but that's a bigger piece that is hard to inject into without seeing your code at present ...

```
Public Sub WriteAgeToCell()
    If Range("A1").Text <> "" Then
        Range("A2") = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(WorksheetFunction.YearFrac(Range("A1"), Now), 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Using `Workbook_Open()` in your Workbook object can be used to automatically recalculate what you need.

So to put it all together, and with a little bit of compromise, you can do the following ...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet, lngAgeCol As Long, lngEndRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim lngStartRow As Long

    With Range("rngHeaderAge")
        Set objSheet = .Worksheet
        lngAgeCol = .Column
        lngStartRow = .Row + 1
    End With

    lngEndRow = objSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

    For i = lngStartRow To lngEndRow
        objSheet.Cells(i, lngAgeCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(RC[-1],NOW()),0))"
    Next
End Sub
```

When the workbook is opened, it will fill down the formula from the row below the header column and then if DOB's are changed during the session, the age will update on the fly.

To make the above work, all you need to do is update the code into the Workbook object within the VBA editor and create a named range against the header for the age column, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Not wanting to use a formula because my fear is the user of the file will break it.... plus it is a file that will have a userform entering info on it so the data will keep getting longer.

Comment: @MarkFisher, the info about the userform is kind of important to the question so I suggest adding that.  That aside, I guess my question to you is, if you have someone (maybe it's yourself) developing a user form then surely they know how to do what you're asking?  The rest of the solution you're putting together must have more complexity than what this question is directly wanting.  I'm not asking you to accept the answer but formula or VBA, the logic exists and that exact logic could be used in a VBA solution.  I've updated my answer but it may not be complete enough for you.

Comment: If you're worried about the user fouling up the formulas, simply apply sheet protection and password protect the cells in question (after making sure that the password is accessible by another venue so that if you win the lottery and move to Trinidad, the file won't be jacked up).

Comment: @ Skin, The above VBA is perfect for calculating what I am needing to do.  Unfortunately I am not able to post a screen shot of the worksheet here... the only update that would be needed is this VBA would need to run down an entire column called "Age 1, Age 2, Age 3" if an only if there is a date listed in the column "DOB 1, DOB 2, DOB 3, DOB 4, etc etc etc"  How would that be done?  Age will always be 1 column to the right of DOB if that helps?

Comment: @MarkFisher, answer updated with "compromise".  The VBA I gave you will fill a formula down instead of calculating and persisting.  It's a better approach.  Feel free to upvote my answer if you haven't already.  ;-)

Comment: @Skin.  Thank you!!!  I do have a question... and I think it is something I can manipulate if I understand how to do it...  There will be about 18 columns where the age will need to be calculated.... so is there a way to make it so that if the Column Name contains "DOB" to add in the Age 1 column to the right... and have it move down the column filling in for every DOB there?

Comment: @MarkFisher, yep, you've already got a major headstart with the concepts in the solution I provided.  You can loop through the headers and process each column that has "Age" in the text (refer to the "InStr" function in VBA) or you can extend the named range I created to include all Age header cells and then loop through each cell in that range and traverse down the rows.  Adapting that to the solution I provided is quite straight forward.  Try and work that yourself and if you struggle, I may be able to help.